# pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user

Tags: linux, security, pam

```
Jun 26 15:58:52 hostme su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user {USER} by root(uid=0)
Jun 26 15:59:02 hostme su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user {USER} by root(uid=0)
Jun 26 15:59:37 hostme su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user {USER} by root(uid=0)
```

Is that something to be worried about? Does this mean someone has shell?

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. You wouldn't happen to have a program called "ntfs-3g" installed, would you? I'm experimenting on my box right now to see if file accesses on my ntfs drives are causing this. *Update:* ntfs drive access doesn't seem to be causing this.

Comment: is this coming from a laptop that is having its lid closed, or a machine that is being put to sleep? I'm finding that this is happening with mine. I can't say for certain that it's the cause of all of the messages, but it's an odd coincidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that is telling you is that someone who is logged in as root has for example su'ed to the user {USER}. Whether this is a problem only you can really know.

Answer (score 0):

After much detective work and experiments on my machine, I've come to the conclusion that on **some** machines, these messages *may* indicate that you shut the lid (in the case of a laptop) or put the machine to sleep. As implied above, every machine and installation is different so only you will really know for sure if this is normal. Nevertheless, I hope that my answer can help you cut down your sleuthing time when trying to find the source of these messages.